# neo4j cypher: stacking results with UNION and WITH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm doing a query like

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE id(a) = {id}

WITH a

MATCH (a)-->(x:x)-->(b:b)

WITH a, x, b

MATCH (a)-->(y:y)-->(b:b)

WITH a, x, y, b

MATCH (b)-->(c:c)

RETURN collect(a), collect(x), collect(y), collect(b), collect(c)
```

what I want here is to have the `b` from `MATCH (a)-->(y:y)-->(b:b)` to be composed of the ones from that line and the ones from the previous `MATCH (a)-->(x:x)-->(b:b)`. The problem I'm having with `UNION` is that its picky about the number and kind of nodes to be passed on the next query, and I'm having trouble understanding how to make it all go together.

What other solution could I use to merge these nodes during the query or just before returning them? (Or if should I do it with `UNION` then how to do it that way...)

(Of course the query up there could be done in other better ways. My real one can't. That is just meant to give a visual example of what I'm looking to do.)

Much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplified query might suit your needs.

I took out all the collect() function calls, as it is not clear that you really need to aggregate anything. For example, there will only be a single 'a' node, so aggregating the 'a's does not make sense.

Please be aware that every row of the result will be for a node labelled *either* 'x' or 'y'. But, since every row has to have *both* the x and y values -- every row will have a null value for one of them.

```
START a=node({id})
MATCH (a)-->(x:x)-->(b:b)-->(c:c)
RETURN a, x, null AS y, b, c
UNION 
MATCH (a)-->(y:y)-->(b:b)-->(c:c)
RETURN a, null AS x, y, b, c
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up in the end was something *like* this

```
MATCH (a)-->(x:x)-->(b1:b)-->(c1:c)
WHERE id(a) = {id} AND NOT (a)-->(:y)-->(b1)

WITH a, collect(x) as xs, collect(DISTINCT b1) as b1s, collect(c1) as c1s

MATCH (a)-->(y:y)-->(b2:b)-->(c2:c)

RETURN a, xs, collect(y), (b1s + collect(b2)), c1s + collect(c2)
```